# Can ffmpeg detect the best settings for a given input file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a view Videos (flv,rm,avi) an I like to convert them to mp4.
But I like to have the smallest File-Size with the "same visual quality"

Is there a "automatic" that can convert the Videos and find the best solution of settings to get the smallest size without loosing visible and audio quality?

I think mp4 compression is much better then RealMedia and so it should be possible to extract a Picture of the Stream convert it and save it as MP4 stream the size should stay the same or be less. (Automatic Settings for every Frame or something) If I convert a video with -crf 18 the size is much more then the original. Is there a way to find the "best" solution for the settings in a automated process?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such magic. If there was, it would be on by default. The way Netflix handles the problem is to encode the file hundreds of times and using machine learning to determine visual fidelity of each result, the choose the best one. It takes thousands of hours of CPU time to do. Look at their ["dynamic optimization" blog posts](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/dynamic-optimizer-a-perceptual-video-encoding-optimization-framework-e19f1e3a277f) to learn more. Your best bet is to use a sane CRF value, and set the x264 preset as slow as you are willing to go.